# Ошибка ValueError в Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Пишу проект на Django, столкнулся с ошибкой, и не понимаю как ее пофиксить, понимаю что возвращается None, но не понимаю почему. Подскажите пожалуйста.

ValueError at /contact/
The view library.contacts.views.contact didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/
Django Version: 3.2.6
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:
The view library.contacts.views.contact didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

views.py

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.shortcuts import render
from library.forms import ContactForm


def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            send_mail(
                cd['subject'],
                cd['message'],
                cd.get('email', 'noreply@example.com'), ['myemail@gmail.com'],)
            return render(request,'thanks.html')
        else:
            form = ContactForm(initial={'subject': 'Мне очень нравится ваш сайт!'}) 
        return render(request, "contact_form.html", {"form": form})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=False,label='Ваш адрес e-mail')
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea) # стр 168

def clean_message(self):
    message = self.cleaned_data['message']
    num_words = len(message.split())
    if num_words < 4:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Слишком мало слов!')
    return message
```

Comment: Потому что условие `if request.method == 'POST'` не выполняется

Comment: Подскажите как переписать код, чтоб выполнялось?

Comment: В html-форме отправлять POST-запрос вместо GET-запроса, наверное?

Comment: Увы, там пост метод ( <form action='' method='post'> {% csrf_token %})

Comment: Тогда откуда у вас взялся GET-запрос?

Comment: Не знаю, проблема в том, что я даже отобразить страницу не могу, по данному URL сразу вылетает ошибка

Comment: Вот значит верните из функции то, что вы хотите чтобы отобразилось на странице, хотя бы тот же render с пустой формой. Сейчас же ваша функция ничего не возвращает

Comment: вот из-за "Увы, там пост метод ( <form action='' method='post'> {% csrf_token %})" у вас и отправляется GET запрос

Comment: так как action не указан, значит вы попадаете на тот же url, который используется только для POST.